# How to activate SSL Certificate in GCP.?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

As I'm trying to add SSL cert to GCP.I followed the path given but when I want to add SSL cert there is nothing happened and just a window will open which shows welcome to app engine but I actually want SSL cert window.
Path is 
App Engine -> Application setting -> SSL certificate

Comment: Did you already define a custom domain?

Comment: Have you deployed your first App Engine app in this project?